# Magento Order total not updating after creating invoice programmatically

Tags: magento

I am creating invoice programmatically. As we are using using Fishbowl inventory and from that we directly generate shipment for orders in magento. So i am creating invoice automatically based on shipment.Now the invoice created successfully but order totals are not updating based on invoice amount.

Here is my code to create invoice from shipment items.  I am using this function in **sales_order_shipment_save_after** event and using Purchase Order as payment method for the order so no capture for invoice.

```
    public function autoInvoiceGenerate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

    $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
    $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->loadByIncrementId($shipment->getIncrementId());

    $shippedItems = $shipment->getAllItems();
    $order = $shipment->getOrder();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());


    try{ 

     if(!$order->canInvoice()) {
            //$order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order cannot be invoiced.', false);
            //$order->save();
            return $this;
     }

     $invoiceQtys = array();
     foreach($shippedItems as $item){
         $invoiceQtys[$item->getOrderItemId()] = $item->getQty();
     }

     if(empty($invoiceQtys)){
        return $this;
     } 



    //START Handle Invoice
    $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice($invoiceQtys);
    $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
    $invoice->register();
    $invoice->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(false);
    $invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
    $invoice->sendEmail(true, '');



    $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Invoice created for shipment #'.$shipment->getData('increment_id').'.', false);
    $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
        ->addObject($invoice)
        ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
    $transactionSave->save();

}
```

Comment: put your code with try.....catch block, so you get idea Is there any issues in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late but if you are still having this problem here my suggestion:

- Save the order associated with the invoice.
- Save the invoice at the end.

This works for me:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)
    ->prepareInvoice($itemsarray);

$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
$invoice->register();
$invoice->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(true);
$invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
$order->save();
Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
    ->addObject($invoice)
    ->addObject($invoice->getOrder())
    ->save();
$invoice->save();
```